# regex extracting first date_time stamp when multiple are present

Tags: regex, r

Given a string with multiple date_time stamps, I would like to **extract the first stamp along with the text preceding it**

- The candidate strings could have one or several time stamps
- subsequent date_time stamps will be separated by `sep="-"`
- There may or may not be text between subsequent date_time stamps, but there will definitely be a sep

date_time format  :

- each individual stamp may or may not contain the time (ie just date)
- if a stamp has time, the format will be either `_HHMM` or `_HHMMSS`
- the date will always be of the format `YYYYMMDD`

---

```
library(stringr)  

string   <- "TEXT_etc_20140530-20140825_1635-"
expected <- "TEXT_etc_20140530"

## using this pattern for the date_time stamp
##  8 digits, optional underscore with 4to6 digits, appearing exactly once, followed by "-"
. (\\d{8}(_\\d{4,6})?){1}-    # I am not concerned with potential of a 5-digit time stamp

## Attempts
pat1 <- "(TEXT)(.*?)(\\d{8}(_\\d{4,6})?){1}-";  str_extract(string, pat=pat1)
pat2 <-            "(\\d{8}(_\\d{4,6})?){1}-";  str_extract(string, pat=pat2)  ## date is correct
pat3 <-       "(.*?)(\\d{8}(_\\d{4,6})?){1}-";  str_extract(string, pat=pat3)
pat4 <-       "(.*?)(\\d{8}){1}-"            ;  str_extract(string, pat=pat4)

## Other potential string patterns
string   <- "TEXT_etc_20140530-diff_txet_20140825_1635-"
string   <- "TEXT_etc_20140530_123456-diff_txet_20140825_1635-"
```

Can you help me spot the error in my regex?

*note to non-`R` users: `R` requires that the escape character `\` itself be escaped, hence the `\\` in the code above*

Comment: Are all the values before the first time-stamp non-numeric?

Comment: Thanks all for the multiple answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace 8 digits followed by anything with those 8 digits:

```
# test data
string  <- c("TEXT_etc_20140530-20140825_1635-",
   "TEXT_etc_20140530-diff_txet_20140825_1635-",
   "TEXT_etc_20140530_123456-diff_txet_20140825_1635-")

sub("(\\d{8}).*", "\\1", string)
## [1] "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530"
```

If the optional time should be preserved then use this instead:

```
sub("(\\d{8}(.\\d{4,6})?)\\b.*", "\\1", string)
## [1] "TEXT_etc_20140530"        "TEXT_etc_20140530"      
## [3] "TEXT_etc_20140530_123456"
```

**Update** Added second solution and made a correction to it.

Comment: It does leave off the time but perhaps i misinterpreted and that's what the OP wants.

Comment: The example did not include a time but if time were to be preserved then use the second `sub` that I have just added.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
strings <- c("TEXT_etc_20140530-20140825_1635-",
    "TEXT_etc_20140530-diff_txet_20140825_1635-",
    "TEXT_etc_20140530_123456-diff_txet_20140825_1635-")

pat <- "^\\w*\\d{8}(_\\d{4,6})?"
str_extract(strings, pat=pat)
```

which returns

```
[1] "TEXT_etc_20140530"      "TEXT_etc_20140530"     "TEXT_etc_20140530_123456"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
pat <- '^(?U)(.*\\d{8}).*$'
gsub(pat, '\\1', string, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530"
```

The `(?U)` tells the parser to find the shortest match.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_first_regex(string, "[^0-9]+\\d{8}")
 #[1] "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530"
```

Or

```
 str_extract(string, "[^0-9]+\\d{8}")
 #[1] "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530" "TEXT_etc_20140530"
```

To extract the time:

```
 stri_extract_first_regex(string, "[^0-9]+\\d{8}(?:_[0-9]{4,6})?")
 #[1] "TEXT_etc_20140530"        "TEXT_etc_20140530"       
 #[3] "TEXT_etc_20140530_123456"


 #data 
 string  <- c("TEXT_etc_20140530-20140825_1635-",
"TEXT_etc_20140530-diff_txet_20140825_1635-",
"TEXT_etc_20140530_123456-diff_txet_20140825_1635-")
```